stuck on how to create formula to check if value = Sunday AND date 1 - date 2 is greater than 72 hours show "fail"
I have a table which pulls out the days of the week from a date stamp and also calculates when a change ended and when it was closed. If a change ended on Sunday, we have set hours to complete this so I am trying to create a change to check if value = Sunday, and the actual end date - completed date >72 hours then its a fail, otherwise a pass.
=IF(AA2<=TIME(72,0,0),(AND(AH2="Friday","pass","fail")))

=IF(AND(AH3="Sunday", AA3<"48"), "Fail", "Pass")

I cant get it formula to work in excel. Once working, I want to calculate if Sunday, then 48 hours, if Saturday, then 72 hours. Monday to Thursday is 24 hours. Friday and Saturday - 72 Hours, Sunday 48 Hours.

=IF(AND(D2="Sunday",(A2-B2)*24>48),"Fail",IF(AND(D2="Saturday",(A2-B2)*24>72),"Fail",IF(AND(D2="Friday",(A2-B2)*24>72),"Fail",IF(AND(D2="Thursday",(A2-B2)*24>24),"Fail",IF(AND(D2="Wednesday",(A2-B2)*24>24),"Fail",IF(AND(D2="Tuesday",(A2-B2)*24>24),"Fail",IF(AND(D2="Monday",(A2-B2)*24>24),"Fail","Pass")))))))
Results should be in Column C, either pass or fail depending on ending day and hours between col A and Col b.

Can you add a sample input  dataset and your expected output?

hi Scott, I have update the question. Sample columns would be A to D.

@KirstieHHunter Sample data is better in tables — and examples for both "Pass" and "Fail" will help to make your example Complete and Verifiable

Based on your updated/changed question, I believe that the following may do what you want:
=IF((B2-A2)>VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(A2),{1,2;2,1;3,1;4,1;5,1;6,3;7,3},2,FALSE),"Fail", "Pass")

Your hour-counts (24, 48, 72) are all integer multiples of days (1, 2, 3), so I am using the days in a hard-coded lookup table {1,2;2,1;3,1;4,1;5,1;6,3;7,3} based directly on the WEEKDAY of the Actual End:



Weekday
Days

Hours




1
2

48


2
1

24


3
1

24


4
1

24


5
1

24


6
3

72


7
3

72



